# jackson deserialize Map object inside List

Tags: json, jackson

I have the following JSON in a file

```
[
    {"numberEnrolledPerMonthPerWeek":
        {
            {"year":"2011","numberEnrolled":0,"weeks":2},
            {"year":"2011","numberEnrolled":0,"weeks":3},
            {"year":"2011","numberEnrolled":0,"weeks":4},
            {"year":"2011","numberEnrolled":0,"weeks":5},
            {"year":"2011","numberEnrolled":0,"weeks":6},
            {"year":"2011","numberEnrolled":0,"weeks":7},
            {"year":"2011","numberEnrolled":0,"weeks":8},
            {"year":"2011","numberEnrolled":0,"weeks":9}        
        }
        ,"country":"Argentina"
    },
]
```

When I use Jackson to deserialise this into a Java object I get the following error

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token
```

i am using the following code

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

```
List<EnrolledEnrolment> enrolments = mapper.readValue(new File("src/main/resources/data/jsonQueriesTestData1.txt"), 
        new TypeReference<List<EnrolledEnrolment>>(){});
```

I have used typeReference for the initial array but do how do I use type Reference for the hashmap inside the object EnrolledEnrolment.

```
private Map<Integer, Enrolled> numberEnrolledPerMonthPerWeek = new HashMap<Integer,Enrolled>();
```

The error is thrown when it tries to parse the 2nd Array? Any ideas

Thanks

Comment: Your JSON is not valid. Could you fix it? Could you also show your EnrolledEnrolment POJO class?

Comment: Yes you were correct my JSON was malformed. thanks

Comment: This doesn't help much while looking for the answer of your question. I can't see what you were using as the key of your map, nor can I tell without guessing what the error in your JSON is. I know it's been a while, but it would be useful if you added an edit.

Comment: Make sure your EnrolledEnrollment bean is similar to json.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from the lack of an actual error in the original post, but I encountered an issue when trying to automatically deserialize JSON to an Object where the JSON contain a Map within a List.

I was seeing this error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value
```

I fixed it be adding `@JsonDeserialize(converter = JsonToMapConverter.class)` to my Map in my POJO.

Where that class looked something like this

```
public class JsonToMapConverter extends StdConverter<String, Map<String, MyPojo>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, MyPojo> convert(String value) {
        try {
            return JsonUtil.convertJsonToMap(value, String.class, MyPojo.class);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Failed to convert String to POJO [%s]", value));
        }
    }

}
```

With the utility method looking like

```
    public static <K,V> Map<K,V> convertJsonToMap(String json, Class<K> key, Class<V> value) throws IOException {
        JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory()
            .constructMapLikeType(Map.class, key, value);
        return mapper.readValue(json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), type);
    }
```